# I have reshuffled a matrix in matlab using randperm , how can I get the index of the older matrix

Tags: matlab

I have 784*6000 data set of training and a label vector of 1*6000. I wanted to reshuffle the data as well as the labels , I  have used randperm function to reshuffle the labels , and I have got the reshuffled vector . how can I get the index of the older labels  so that I can select the data set  also accordingly . Can anybody help me
please see the  toy code

```
%toy program 
%label is given for 9 data set 
label =[ 1 1 1 2 2 2 3  3  3];
label= label';
data = [1 0 0 ; 1 0 0 ; 1 0 0 ;0 1 0; 0 1 0 ; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 1; 0 0 1  ];

shuffledlabel =label(randperm(size(label,1)),:);
resizedlabel= shuffledlabel(1:5,:);

% I want to resize the data also based on the resized labels
```

Comment: Can you add the code of how you used randperm to shuffle your labels? :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here at SO, we are helping each other with problems we face while programming. So in order to get help from the community, you should be more specific with your problem. What have you tried so far? Please provide some of your code, or otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: if you used randperm(n,k) to shuffle your index vector and you want your 784*6000 matrix to follow that index, you should be able to use a for loop and update each column by setting New(:,t) = Old(:,Ind(t))

Comment: I have added a toy code

Comment: Thank u very much for pointing out my mistake of not adding the code

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
ind_shuffle = randperm(size(label,1));
shuffledlabel = label(ind_shuffle);
[~, ind_deshuffle] = sort(ind_shuffle); %// index to recover original order
deshuffledlabel = shuffledlabel(ind_deshuffle);
```

Comment: Thank You very much ! This s what I wanted .

Comment: @sollybennet please don't forget to accept Luis's answer since it solved your problem. Thanks!